# Why won't anything be printed when i use selenium to webscrape letterboxd?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def search_letterboxd_by_genre(genre):
    url = f"https://letterboxd.com/films/genre/{genre}/"

    # Set up the Selenium webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run browser in headless mode (without GUI)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the page to load
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    # Find all movie elements with the class name "film-poster"
    movie_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "frame")

    if movie_elements:
        for movie_element in movie_elements:
            try:
                movie_title = movie_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "img").get_attribute("alt")
                print(movie_title)
            except:
                print("Error extracting movie title.")
    else:
        print("No movies found for the given genre.")

    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()
```

This is the code (I have called the function and added an input statement, but just haven't copied it)

At first I was using beautiful soup but read somewhere that selenium is able to overcome the javascript so the movie titles will print but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:** After the URL is launched, a <kbd>Consent</kbd> pop-up appears(see below). You need to get rid of that pop-up first. After that try to scrape.

[image]

**Refer the working code below:**

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

url = f"https://letterboxd.com/films/genre/action/"

# Set up the Selenium webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run browser in headless mode (without GUI)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
# Wait for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Consent']").click()
time.sleep(10)
movie_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='films-browser-list-container']//li//a//span[1]")

for movie in movie_elements:
    print(movie.get_attribute("innerText"))

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

**Console output:**

```
Everything Everywhere All at Once (2022)
Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse (2018)
Inception (2010)
The Dark Knight (2008)
Spider-Man: No Way Home (2021)
Avengers: Infinity War (2018)
Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse (2023)
Avengers: Endgame (2019)
Baby Driver (2017)
Black Panther (2018)
Guardians of the Galaxy (2014)
Kill Bill: Vol. 1 (2003)
The Matrix (1999)
Scott Pilgrim vs. the World (2010)
Spider-Man: Homecoming (2017)
Avatar: The Way of Water (2022)
Thor: Ragnarok (2017)
The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)
Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness (2022)
Star Wars (1977)
Top Gun: Maverick (2022)
Deadpool (2016)
Spider-Man: Far from Home (2019)
Mad Max: Fury Road (2015)
Dunkirk (2017)
The Avengers (2012)
Avatar (2009)
Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3 (2023)
Puss in Boots: The Last Wish (2022)
Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 (2017)
The Empire Strikes Back (1980)
Tenet (2020)
Bullet Train (2022)
Doctor Strange (2016)
Iron Man (2008)
Captain America: Civil War (2016)
Spider-Man (2002)
Star Wars: The Force Awakens (2015)
The Incredibles (2004)
The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)
Captain America: The Winter Soldier (2014)
The Dark Knight Rises (2012)
John Wick (2014)
Thor: Love and Thunder (2022)
The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)
Spider-Man 2 (2004)
Batman Begins (2005)
Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)
Star Wars: The Last Jedi (2017)
Black Widow (2021)
The Suicide Squad (2021)
Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings (2021)
Captain Marvel (2019)
Return of the Jedi (1983)
Rogue One: A Star Wars Story (2016)
Ant-Man (2015)
Black Panther: Wakanda Forever (2022)
Logan (2017)
Star Wars: Episode III – Revenge of the Sith (2005)
Captain America: The First Avenger (2011)
Oldboy (2003)
The Northman (2022)
Léon: The Professional (1994)
Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker (2019)
The Amazing Spider-Man (2012)
Kill Bill: Vol. 2 (2004)
Raiders of the Lost Ark (1981)
Star Wars: Episode I – The Phantom Menace (1999)
Deadpool 2 (2018)
Iron Man 3 (2013)
Eternals (2021)
Scarface (1983)

Process finished with exit code 0
```